# C# Load in a DLL at runtime, second load does not work

Tags: c#, .net, dll, runtime, remoting

I am generating C# code and compiling it to a DLL at runtime, and then loading the DLL into the program and calling its methods.

But when I compile the DLL again and try to load it in, .NET already thinks it has the DLL loaded and so does not re-load the DLL. I can tell this is the case as any methods I call still act in the same way even though I changed their code. Also on restarting my program the methods start working as expected.

I understand that at this point the usual advice is to use a second `AppDomain` and add `MarshalByRef` to all my classes, but this approach is not working for me; inside the DLL I need to cast incoming data which doesn't work when using remoting as the object is a `__TransparentProxy` and casting it to what I need returns null.

So my other option as far as I can see is to trick .NET into thinking it's loading a different DLL/type into the program so it actually loads it.

So far I have tried:

1. Each time I compile the code into the DLL, the DLL is output to a different folder from before.
2. Adding a GUID to the type I am trying to load so the type always has a different name
3. Changing the GUID in the AssemblyInfo.cs file

...but still the new DLL is not loaded in. Even changing the output folder, looking at the property `assembly.Location' shows the old DLL path. so what is still making it think it is the same?

How I load the DLL at runtime:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllFilePath);
Type type = assembly.GetTypes().Single(t => t.BaseType.Name == "Parser");

var classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
return classInstance as Parser;
```

Comment: You already know what you need to do, AppDomain is essential.  You really do have to work on the "not working for me" problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `Assembly.LoadFrom` method will load new assembly if it has a different identity. Give a unique name to the newly generated **assembly** (not only the file name).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx